# Getting the coordinate of mouse click in C

Tags: c, mouse, dos, turbo-c

I found this header file on google to perform mouse related events in C program but i am having no idea of `int86` `union REGS i,o;` and what are other `int86` type functions available in C? I am using windows OS and Turbo C.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

initmouse();
void showmouseptr();
void restrictmousept(int,int,int,int);
void getmousepos(int *,int *,int *);
void hidemouseptr();

union REGS i,o;
initmouse()
{
     i.x.ax=0;
     int86(0x33,&i,&o);
     return(o.x.ax);
}
void showmouseptr()
{
   i.x.ax=1;
   int86(0x33,&i,&o);
}
void restrictmouseptr(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
{
   i.x.ax=7;
   i.x.cx=x1;
   i.x.dx=x2;
   int86(0x33,&i,&o);
   i.x.ax=8;
   i.x.cx=y1;
   i.x.dx=y2;
   int86(0x33,&i,&o);
}
void getmousepos(int *button,int *x,int *y)
{
  i.x.ax=3;
  int86(0x33,&i,&o);
  *button=o.x.bx;
  *x=o.x.cx;
  *y=o.x.dx;
}

void hidemouseptr()
{
   i.x.ax=2;
   int86(0x33,&i,&o);
}
```

Comment: This looks like 16-bit DOS. What operating system and what compiler are you using?

Comment: The C language standard do not know what a mouse is. You probably need to use some operating-system specific library for that purpose. For instance, using GTK you want to use its http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-motion-notify-event

Comment: This code seems to try to issue syscalls and retrieve the values directly from the CPU registers - you probably don't want this.

Comment: @Basile: Give him a break, he is a newcomer. We've all been through there, trying to handle some clicks and do funny things. :)

Comment: Turbo C has built-in help, listing and describing all the entities supported by the compiler. Press Shift+F1.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like old code for MS-DOS to user the x86 interrupts to call system functions to get mouse coordinates.  I would be surprised if this code still works in a command prompt of any modern computer.  In fact, the header file at the top including dos.h would give this away.

in86() is how you "interrupt" the CPU in DOS mode.  It is sort of the way functions are called in modern day operating systems.  More info here:  http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_INT86_function_in_C_programming

A union is a method in C of defining data which can be accessed in different ways.  More here:  http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15.

It is unclear what you are trying to do, let alone what operating system you are running under.  You probably want to pick a language first (C# might be a good start, assuming you are using Windows) and then look at the base class library for WinForms to learn how to respond to mouse events.   There are fine tutorials on WinForms which will teach you how to respond to the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Discard that code: it is old 16-bit DOS which probably is not what you want.

It seems you're rather new to C. In that case, a better advice is to *study well the language*; check around the site for good learning references. "The C Programming Language", by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan is a good starting point.

Having said that, there are no `int86` functions "in C". These are Borland Turbo C extensions. That was how one could manipulate the mouse in DOS, but nowadays it is different.

Note that the C language is, fundamentally, simply a programming language. It is intended to express algorithms. However, the C language standard also gives you a *standard library*: a set of predefined types, functions and macros you can use, to save time and portability. This library addresses some basic functionality, and mouse input handling is not one of them.

In other words, after you have studied C, you'll be ready to deal with specific operating system's APIs. This is needed, because the C standard library offers no way to manipulate any sort of input devices. You will also study some fundamentals regarding how input is handled in modern operating systems. For example, to handle mouse input you will most likely need to create a *window* (or *widget*) in order to receive mouse events -- implying that you will have to read a bit about the underlying windowing API.

There are some libraries which accesses the system's APIs for you and factor out the differences, offering you a programming alternative. It should be no different, though, from studying and using the system's API directly, except possibly for enhanced portability.

Comment: Turbo c Is Official Compiler to tech in India. My Teacher Scold me because I was using eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 1):

The int86 function calls the DOS Mouse Interrupt 33h. A dos interrupt is specific to the msdos operating system, so your code is only usable under msdos. 'union REGS' are the input and output registers that are used as parameters for the DOS interrupt. A DOS interrupt is similar to a system call in other operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `dosbox` if you want to run `turbo C` programs under Windows/Linux etc

For example, on Windows, just make a desktop link that runs a batch script to run your program in `dosbox`, this is how the steam version of Doom works I think